# Passing variable between functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the variable `word1` in the first function to the second function in pure JavaScript?

```
function functionOne()
{
    var word1 = "dog" ;
}

function functionTwo()
{
    var word2= word1;
}
```

I've checked the other questions in stackoverflow on this subject but I didn't get a simple answer.

Comment: Do you call functionTwo from functionOne ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating common variable** as below resolve your issue

```
var _common;

function functionOne()
{
    var word1 = "dog" ;
   _common= word1;
}

function functionTwo()
{
    var word2= _common;
}
```

Comment: Using a global variable just for that?

Comment: @Laurent suggest this way because not clear what actually OP want...

Comment: @PranayRana It will be better if you remove the last sentence from your answer.

Comment: @dystroy - my bad i m still not got what OP wants but remove cookie from answer...

Comment: @VisioN - removed i just given the option because i m not clear what actually OP wants..anyways thanks

Comment: Thank you Pranay Rana, it worked.

Comment: I like to use _common instead of common. this will make me remember that it's global 
@Tresk

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha - updated answer according ot it but i think its not going to make any difference...just code clarity

Answer (score 7):

Use arguments:

```
function functionOne() {
    var word1 = "dog";
    functionTwo(word1);
}

function functionTwo(word1) {
    var word2 = word1;
}
```

Comment: There's no `functionTwo` call in the question. So, I assume, there is a third function, that calls them both. If so, it would be implemeted through return value. Could you show this case also?

Answer (score -3):

I assume you need a global declaration for `word1` since you don't allow any parameters to be passed into `functionTwo`.

There are plenty of resources here at SO, please do a more thorough search next time.

[Passing variables between functions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=passing%20variables%20functions%20javascript%20%5Bjavascript%5D)

I am not going to discuss the pros vs cons of global variables here.